# Как проверить, что нажато две кнопки с клавиатуры?

Tags: c#, wpf

Я не могу определить, что нажаты две кнопки Shift + Tab. Получается только поймать событие нажатия одной кнопки

```
1)
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key == Key.Tab)
        // работает
    else if (e.Key == Key.LeftShift && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Tab))
        // не работает
}

2)
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Tab))
        // работает
    else if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Tab) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift))
        // не работает
}
```

Comment: Пробовали так: `if (e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)`?

Comment: И попробуйте не на `KeyDown`,  на `PreviewKeyDown`.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось

Comment: Но это вроде бы не WPF, да?

Comment: Пожалуйста! Перенесу в ответ.

Comment: Это WPF, но комментарий мне помог додумать решение. Сделал для `PreviewKeyDown`, обработку Shift + Tab поставил в `if`, а просто Shift - в `else if` и сделал как в вашем ответе ниже для WPF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На WinForms:

```
e.Shift && e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab
```

На WPF:

```
e.Key == Key.Tab && ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) == ModifierKeys.Shift)
```

И лучше, по идее, ловить на `PreviewKeyDown`.

---

С другой стороны, вам по идее не должно этого хотеться. Обработка Tab-навигации делается встроенными контролами автоматически. Если вы переключаетесь между поддокументами, перехват Shift-Tab и правильную реакцию на него должен делать tab control (или чем там вы пользуетесь) самостоятельно.